# Get items in a multidimensional array-like object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following variable:

```
> let location = {0: {1: {name: 'Fred', age: 20}, 5: {name: 'Ema', age: 55}}, 9: {3: {name: 'John', age: 29}}};
```

And I want to get the items in it:

```
> console.log(get_items(location));
[{name: 'Fred', age: 20}, {name: 'Ema', age: 55}, {name: 'John', age: 29}]
```

I've written the following function:

```
function get_items(location) {
  return _.values(location).reduce((items, item)=> items.concat(_.values(item)), []);
}
```

But I wonder if there is a more elegant solution for this problem.

Comment: Your approach seems to me absolutely fine. Furthermore, from performance standpoint `.reduce()` is doing much better, than `.flatMap()`. And, as long as I started talking performance, you re-create unnecessarily accumulator within `.reduce()` by using `.concat()`, to gain some efficiency, I'd rather do `_.values(location).reduce((items, item) => (items.push(_.values(item)), items), [])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with `Array#flatMap` and `Object#values`

- The `Object#values` will extract the *value(s)* of the outer object:
- The `Array#flatMap` would map and flatten the nested objects into a single array of objects after extracting the *value* by applying the `Object#values` again for each object:

```js
let data = {0: {1: {name: 'Fred', age: 20}, 5: {name: 'Ema', age: 55}}, 9: {3: {name: 'John', age: 29}}};
const transform = (data) => Object.values(data).flatMap(Object.values);

console.log(transform(data));
```